# Disable and Enable a TabPage in C#

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I am using **Windows Forms** application using C#.I would like to know, how can I disable the `TabPages` while it is not open or selected and it can be open by using another button.

Specifically, I want to disable the `TabControl` of `TabPages` and `TabPages` can be controlled by button click using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have to remove the tab and re-add it when you want it

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage1); // Hide the tab page
tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, tabPage1);// Show the tab page (insert it to the correct position)
```

For example:

1. Hiding a TabPage

   ```
   private void ButtonHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage1);
   }
   ```
2. Showing a TabPage

   ```
   private void ButtonShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage1);
   }
   ```